# how to change the case creator

Tags: workflow, data-loader, fields, update, system-fields

I want to be able to change the case creator (I have a workflow rule that fires an email when the case goes to "waiting on update" and sometimes the case creator needs to be updated to prevent the email going to the wrong recipient).

Comment: By "case creator", do you mean the Case Owner field? And do you want to update it in code, or a workflow, or the UI?

Comment: I mean the "CreatedByID" field (I can export this in DataLoader). I want to update via the Data Loader or UI or through the dev console

Comment: ok! Then yep, the Ninja's answer of a custom field to be the e-mail target is the only way for the reasons he gave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a system generated audit field.  You can contact SF support to open it up, but that is only a window of time and they won't leave it open indefinitely.  Also, you can only insert new objects and set the CreatedById, you can't update existing objects.  Due to this, I dint think you can reset this field in a workflow.

If it's an email your worried about sending you can add a custom email field or even a custom user lookup field and use that field to reset and have your WFR send to the appropriate person.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new l/u field to the user object and that works nicely.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked :)